# How to adjust the bottom sheet to the child intrinsic height?

Tags: flutter, bottom-sheet

Here is the simplified code:

```dart
class BottomSheetContent extends StatelessWidget {

  @override 
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Hello")),
      body:  Container(
        color: Colors.pink,
        height: 120,
        child: Text("Hello"),
      ),
    );
  }
}


// And further down in the app:

OutlinedButton(
  onPressed: () => showModalBottomSheet(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) => BottomSheet(
      onClosing: () {},
      builder: (context) => BottomSheetContent()
    )
  )
)
```

The result to achieve is to have the bottom sheet to match the child height.

Here is the dart pad:

[https://dartpad.dev/?id=08a2345fd30f2d2d7431729110ba261a"](https://dartpad.dev/?id=08a2345fd30f2d2d7431729110ba261a%22)

Comment: Hey, did you try  isScrollControlled: true ?